# VS Load Test Think Time Factor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

I can specify a think time for my visual studio 2012 load test. But is it possible, to give the think time a factor like: 40*{{factor}}

If factor = 2, my think time is 80s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will work, but you can give it a try.

1. Create a LoadTest plugin and in the Initialize method set the `DelayBetweenIterations` value you want:

   ```
   public class Plugin : ILoadTestPlugin
   {
       private Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.LoadTesting.LoadTest _mLoadTest;

       public void Initialize(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.LoadTesting.LoadTest loadTest)
       {
           _mLoadTest.Scenarios[0].DelayBetweenIterations = 40 * factor;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add your plugin to your load test by right click to the load test --> Add Load Test PlugIn...

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean after each request. Edit your question and add the structure of your LoadTest. Are those request different tests inside the same load test scenario?